# Can Polymodel classes be used with Basemodel in the Google App Engine Django Helper?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

The Django Helper for Google App Engine creates BaseModel to allow a model to exist both in Django and App Engine. Does the helper provide a way to use Polymodels with Django?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is here.  BaseModel derives from db.Model.  Are you asking if you can change the helper to have BaseModel derive from PolyModel?

Comment: @dar: I am interested in whether the helper provides a method of using Polymodels with Django. The specifics are unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any functionality in the helper to incorporate Polymodel.   I think you're going to have to change `BaseModel` to inherit from `Polymodel` and test it out to see if anything breaks.

There was a question about this here, but no one responded.  There's been some activity lately on the mailing list, so you might want to raise it again: http://groups.google.com/group/app-engine-django/browse_thread/thread/cdaba1ed81a9d958